# Is there a way for accuracy backtick notation to accept variable inputs?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

Backtick notation uses

```
1.0``20
```

to give 1 with 20 places of accuracy after the decimal point. But what I want is

```
acc=20
1.0``acc
```

so that I can easily change the accuracy of all my calculations. Is this possible?

Comment: How about using a simple factor, as in  `acc=1``20;12*acc`?

Comment: [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html)?

Comment: @Jens `Accuracy[12*acc]` is 18.92.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's right, but it looked like he wants something that can be stuck into individual parts of a longer expression, whereas `SetAccuarcy` is more "volatile" (i.e., has to wrap the entire expression).

Comment: @Jens I've wanted the same thing at times, but I don't know of any easy way to do it, since the back ticks are not operators. It would be like setting `fraction = 23456` and wanting `1.fraction` to translate to `1.23456`.

Comment: I can only imagine doing this with [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PreRead.html).

Comment: You could write an awful function like `ack[acc_][x_]:=ToExpression[ToString@x<>"``"<>ToString@acc]` and do `1.00//ack[20]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah I guess the goal is something convenient like the backticks, for when I need to specify the accuracy very often but would rather not clutter things up.

Comment: @N.J.Evans That's not a bad solution, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Compare ``0.200000000000001 // ack[20]`` and ```0.200000000000001``20```.  -- As I said, I have yet to figure out how to do this without the actual input string to the FE (i.e., via  `$PreRead`).

Answer (score 1):

*[Personally, I would be satisfied with [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html), at least in the use-cases in which I imagine I would need it.  It just seems easier to me to learn how to work with the system instead of around it.  Nonetheless, it seems to be possible....]*

Here's an idea of what I was talking about with [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PreRead.html) in a comment.  On a syntax error, it might fail spectacularly, but it seems to work on correct input.

```
$PreRead = # //. 
   RowBox[{x___, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, __ ~~ "``"], a_, y___}] :>
    RowBox[{x, s <> ToString@ToExpression@a, y}] &
```

It evaluates the box form representing the accuracy and appends its value after the ``` `` ``` in the input.

Then

```
acc = 10;
1.23``(2 acc)
(*  1.2300000000000000000  *)

Accuracy[%]
(*  20.  *)
```

And

```
10.23``acc + 4.56``(2 acc)
(*  14.790000000  *)

Accuracy[%]
(*  10.  *)
```

The standard accuracy input syntax works:

```
1.23``20
(*  1.2300000000000000000  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [`Notation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) package to help.

```
<< Notation`
```

[image]

```
Notation[a_ \[ScriptA] b_\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] N[Rationalize[a_,0],{Infinity,b_}]]
```

I used a picture of a cell here to make it clear that this has been entered via the Notation palette

[image]

Now you can use

```
list=Table[10.75\[ScriptA] k,{k,1,10}]
(* {11.,10.8,10.75,10.750,10.7500,10.75000,10.750000,10.7500000,10.75000000,10.750000000} *)
```

or

```
k=10;

Accuracy /@ 
 NestList[(1.25 \[ScriptA] k) (# - 0.2 \[ScriptA] k) &, 
  1 \[ScriptA] k, 50]
(* {10., 9.48149, 9.20936, 9.01016, 8.84585, 8.70167, 8.57032, \
8.44771, 8.33128, 8.21936, 8.1108, 8.00479, 7.90074, 7.7982, 7.69684, \
7.5964, 7.49669, 7.39755, 7.29886, 7.20054, 7.1025, 7.00469, 6.90706, \
6.80957, 6.7122, 6.61493, 6.51772, 6.42058, 6.32348, 6.22642, \
6.12939, 6.03239, 5.9354, 5.83843, 5.74147, 5.64452, 5.54758, \
5.45064, 5.35371, 5.25679, 5.15986, 5.06294, 4.96602, 4.86911, \
4.77219, 4.67528, 4.57837, 4.48145, 4.38454, 4.28763, 4.19072} *)
```

vs

```
Accuracy /@ NestList[(1.25``10) (# - 0.2``10) &, 1.0``10, 50]
(* {10., 9.48149, 9.20936, 9.01016, 8.84585, 8.70167, 8.57032, \
8.44771, 8.33128, 8.21936, 8.1108, 8.00479, 7.90074, 7.7982, 7.69684, \
7.5964, 7.49669, 7.39755, 7.29886, 7.20054, 7.1025, 7.00469, 6.90706, \
6.80957, 6.7122, 6.61493, 6.51772, 6.42058, 6.32348, 6.22642, \
6.12939, 6.03239, 5.9354, 5.83843, 5.74147, 5.64452, 5.54758, \
5.45064, 5.35371, 5.25679, 5.15986, 5.06294, 4.96602, 4.86911, \
4.77219, 4.67528, 4.57837, 4.48145, 4.38454, 4.28763, 4.19072} *)
```